# Object instantiated in prefab's position not on object in scene position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

On clicking the button, I call the Shoot () function, which should create a bullet in the place of the character, but creates in the center of the scene, because prefab's position is 0,0,0. I need to instantiate bullet in position of object in scene.

This code is attached to character object.

```
using Photon.Pun;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class PlayerShooter : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _bullet;
    [SerializeField] private float _distanceMultiplier;
 
    public void Shoot()
    {
        if (PhotonNetwork.PlayerList.Length > 1)
        {
            PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(_bullet.name, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Positions and rotations are always respect to the parent. You beed to make the bullet children of the character and then its 0,0,0 will be respect to the character, so the character's position in the world.
Same happen for rotations and scale. They compose along the gameObjects hierarchy and the `.local` will be always respect to the parent.
If the hierarchy of your object is deep, you dont need to make the transformation along all the hierarchy yourself, you can use:

- [Transform.TransformPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html)
- [Transform.InverseTransformPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html)

To switch between local and world spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with this code:

```
using Photon.Pun;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerShooter : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _bullet;
    [SerializeField] private float _distanceMultiplier;

    [HideInInspector] public Button shootButton;

    private void Start()
    {
        shootButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate () { Shoot(); });
    }

    public void Shoot()
    {
        if (PhotonNetwork.PlayerList.Length > 1)
        {
            PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(_bullet.name, transform.position + transform.up * _distanceMultiplier, transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```